# real world haskell compile fail tempfile.hs

Tags: haskell

Compile the ch07 tempfile.hs,  it report below error.  how to fix it?

```
        import System.IO
        import System.Directory(getTemporaryDirectory, removeFile)
        import System.IO.Error(catch)
        import Control.Exception(finally)

    tempfile.hs:4:24: error:
       Module System.IO.Error does not export catch
      |
    4 | import System.IO.Error(catch)
      |                        ^^^^^
```

Comment: I'm afraid that if you're following Real World Haskell you're going to get a lot of this type of problem. The book is well over 10 years old and I'm not sure it has ever been updated - certainly not since a few years after being made. Lots of the libraries it uses have been significantly reorganised and/or have very different public APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't necessarily have to give up on reading Real World Haskell. I think you can easily fix the most common "`Foo` does not export `bar`" errors by looking up `bar` in [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/). In this case the results for `catch` are:

[image: Hoogle results for "catch"]

Hoogle cannot find all possible results, but it should find the results from the most well-maintained and the most popular packages.

The words of the green line of text below each result which start with a lowercase letter are the names of the packages that export this function. The `base` package is one of the most fundamental package, so if your function is defined there, then you should probably choose that version. You can see that that is the case for the first result.

The rest of the green line of text are the modules from which the function is exported. For the first result that is `Control.Exception`, `Control.Exception.Base`, and `GHC.IO`. Modules starting with `GHC` should be avoided if possible, these require specific implementation details of the GHC compiler, which is not a big problem, but it also indicates that it is probably not a standard module. Additionally, I would recommend choosing the name with the fewest `.`'s, so `Control.Exception` and not `Control.Exception.Base`, because those are the most general modules.

Another thing that you should watch out for are modules that contain the name `Internal`. An example can be seen in the green line below the second result, namely `System.Directory.Internal.Prelude`. These modules are have no guarantee to be stable across versions of the package that contains them, so you should also avoid these unstable modules.

So, in this case you can choose to import `catch` from `Control.Exception`. To do that you can just remove the line with `System.IO.Error` and add `catch` to the list of imports from the `Control.Exception` module:

```
import Control.Exception(finally, catch)
```